# Setting a threshold download size for uGet

Tags: uget

I have been using uGet to facilitate large downloads, but my problem is, it starts even for small downloads (~ 1-5 mb), which I do not want (rather happy with the normal download mode of the browser). Is there any way I can set a threshold value for downloads in uGet? 
edit:  I installed uGet browser integration extension (2.1.3.1) in firefox (which i think replaced the default download manager) and something called curl and aria2, and in my uget settings, the plugin matching order is set to curl.

Comment: How did you make uGet your default download option instead of the browser itself? Did you use some application(s)/extension(s)? If so, please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: well, i'm sort of a newbie in this domain, so i just followed some instruction in a web-page (don't remember which), but i remember installing uGet browser integration extension (2.1.3.1) in firefox (which i think replaced the default download manager) and something called curl and aria2, though in my uget settings, the plugin matching order is set to curl. would this help? @pomsky (thank you for your comments!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a uGet icon next to the addressbar (if you don't see any, right click and select "Customise..." and then drag the icon). The following dialogue should pop up:

[image]

Set a threshold value (in KB) for "Minimum file size".

Comment: Thanks a ton! I should've seen it before, but missed it somehow. It's working but in the box where it says "Found uGet and uget-integrator", mine says "unable to connect with uget-integrator". But it works anyway! Thanks again. :)